# What does "mount" mean in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, router

I'm learning Express.js and I came across this definition:

"An Express router provides a subset of Express methods. To create an instance of one, we invoke the .Router() method on the top-level Express import.
To use a router, we ***mount*** it at a certain path using app.use() and pass in the router as the second argument."

What does "mount" mean?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It means adding it to the application. Normal usage of [English (7)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mount#Verb): "*To attach (an object) to a support, backing, framework etc.*" (also 8, 14, 15) - not really related to express.

Comment: Mount. Means this `app.use(router)`. With mount they mean you put it inside `app.use()`

Answer (score 1):

Mount simply means it prepends the path to your routes.

Say for example your routes have the following endpoints:

```
/list
/create
/update
/get/:id
```

And you **mount** it to `/api/tasks`. The endpoints will be:

```
/api/tasks/list
/api/tasks/create
/api/tasks/update
/api/tasks/get/:id
```

The way it's done in Express is:

```
const routes = require('./my/routes');

app.use('/api/tasks',routes);
```

> Note: This terminology comes from how disks/drives work on Unix (Linux, MacOS etc.). Unlike Windows where disks are **mounted** to letters like `C:` or `D:` on Unix disks are **mounted** to folders. So for example if you connect a thumb drive named "Stuff" on Linux you will find a new folder called:
>
> ```
>    /media/your_username/Stuff
> ```
>
> And this folder will contain all the data of the thumbdrive. This is done by the automounter but you can also manually mount drives to empty folders. For example if I install the right software on my machine I can mount a remote shared drive to `/Users/my_username/projects/shared_drives/shared_pictures`.
>
> So it's natural for programmers to call the act of adding things to paths **mounting**.